# PHP Condition Total records

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I'm developing a simple condition where I want to show an HTML code only if the total number of rows from a recordset is greater than `1`. The HTML content is not showing, what could be the best condition option?

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_user = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_user, "int"));
$user = mysql_query($query_user, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
$totalRows_user = mysql_num_rows($user);

<?php
if ($totalRows_user > 1) {
    ?>
 <a href="excluiru.php?id=<?php echo $row_user['id']; ?>">
<img src="imagens/delete.png" alt="Remover" onClick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this User?');" /></a>Delete User
      <?php 
    } ?>
```

UPDATE: I discover that `mysql_num_rows($user);` is giving a value of zero all the time.
Is there another way to count?

I found and solve the Problem :D

```
<?php
$isExist = mysql_query("select COUNT(id) from users");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($isExist);
if($r['COUNT(id)'] > 1){
    ?>
```

I should not be using the totalrows but the fetch_array

Comment: It's throwing an error or something....what if instead of >1 you put >0 ??

Comment: if it gives a zero counting another way is not going to help. debug - hard code the id number to see what happen. echo `$query_user` to see if query is right also `echo $colname_user;`

Comment: Well, i should be using the fetch_query, not the total_num_row!

Comment: use can use both but you are using mysql_fetch_assoc which is what you would replace if needed. one to count records and the other to display them. urm that does not solve your problem as where is the where filter?

Answer (score 1):

as there will be 1 record it will never be greater than 1.

```
if ($totalRows_user > 1)
```

should be

```
if ($totalRows_user == 1)
```

anything with debug you can delete once its working

```
$colname_user = 1; // debug

$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;","root","");
$ami = $db->prepare('SELECT count(*),id FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$ami->bindParam(':id', $colname_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ami->execute();

print_r($ami->errorInfo()); // debug

$totalRows_user = $ami->fetchColumn();
$result = $ami->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row_user = $ami->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    print_r($row_user); // debug

    }

<?php
if ($totalRows_user == 1) {
    ?>
 <a href="excluiru.php?id=<?php echo $row_user['id']; ?>">
<img src="imagens/delete.png" alt="Remover" onClick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this User?');" /></a>Delete User
      <?php 
    } ?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Well! I believe i'm using something wrong.
I tried it but it's not working :(

Answer (score 1):

or

```
if ($totalRows_user >= 1)
```

Comment: IDK! But the record it's not working!
Am i using the right variable?

Comment: Why not `echo` out each variable. then you can start to debug it properly.

Comment: As Nick R says you have to be sure that you are getting the data from db. try this print_r($row_user), to see if you are getting the array, and you should change to mysqli extention

Comment: if mysql_num_rows($user) is equal to zero you have to check your query or check if the data is correct...I don't know how work the function GetSQLValueString()...but the problem may be there...in the query

Answer (score 0):

@emilio-gort and @amigura have it right, however it should be mentioned that PHP 5.5 (just released) deprecates the MySQL extension. You should be using MySQLI or PDO instead, both of which provide proper sanitization, which should take care of Bobby Tables that @nick-r mentioned.

Comment: I did understood! But since i'm not a PHP expert and i did everything on Dreamweaver!